# How to find minimum number of steps to sort an integer array

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an integer array  `int[] number = { 3,4,2,5,1};`

The minimum number of steps to sort it should be 2. But I am getting 4.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] number = { 3,4,2,5,1};

           int result =  get_order(number);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static int get_order(int[] input1)
        {
            input1 = input1.OrderByDescending(o => o).ToArray();
            bool flag = true;
            int temp;
            int numLength = input1.Length;
            int passes = 0;

            for (int i = 1; (i <= (numLength - 1)) && flag; i++)
            {
                flag = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < (numLength - 1); j++)
                {
                    if (input1[j + 1] > input1[j])
                    {
                        temp = input1[j];
                        input1[j] = input1[j + 1];
                        input1[j + 1] = temp;
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
                passes++;
            }
            return passes+1;
        }
```

What is the problem and what changes i need to do in my code?

Edit

implement @Patashu, algorithm,

```
public static int get_order(int[] input1)
        {
            var sorterArray = input1.OrderByDescending(o => o).ToArray();
            var unsortedArray = input1;
            int temp1;
            int swap = 0;

            int arrayLength = sorterArray.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
            {
                if (sorterArray[i] != unsortedArray[i])
                {
                    temp1 = unsortedArray[i];
                    unsortedArray[i] = sorterArray[i];
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < arrayLength; j++)
                    {
                        if (unsortedArray[j] == sorterArray[i])
                        {
                            unsortedArray[j] = temp1;
                            swap++;
                            break;
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }

            return swap;
        }
```

Comment: What do you define as a "step"? Also it's descending in this case?

Comment: but i need to find out how many minimum steps it takes to sort...how will i do it using linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your algorithm is that it only attempts swapping adjacent elements.

3,4,2,5,1 is best sorted by swapping 3 with 5, which is an unadjacent swap, and then 2 with 3.

So, I suggest that you will find a better algorithm by doing the following:

1) First, sort the array into descending order using the built in sorting function of C#.

2) Now, you can use this sorted array as a comparison - iterate through the array from left to right. Every time you see an element in the unsorted array that is != to the element in the same space in the sorted array, look deeper into the unsorted array for the value the sorted array has there, and do one swap.

e.g.

3,4,2,5,1

Sort using Sort -> 5,4,3,2,1 is our sorted array

3 is != 5 - look in unsorted array for 5 - found it, swap them.

Unsorted is now 5,4,2,3,1

4 == 4

2 is != 3 - look in unsorted array for 3 - found it, swap them.

Unsorted is now 5,4,3,2,1

2 == 2

1 == 1

We're at the end of the unsorted array and we did two swaps.

EDIT: In your algorithm implementation, it looks almost right except

instead of

```
unsortedArray[j] = sorterArray[i];
unsortedArray[i] = temp1;
```

you had it backwards, you want

```
unsortedArray[j] = temp1;
unsortedArray[i] = sorterArray[i];
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well. Somewhat similar to Levenshtein distance for strings?

Comment: I'm not convinced by this method at all. Unless you brute force all possible swaps you are not going to arrive at the optimal solutions. It is *extremely* convenient that it even works out for this case.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi You are saying it is not possible to write this algorithm faster than O(n^2)?

Comment: @Patashu No, I'm saying this method as it currently stands does not find the correct value. And brute forcing all swaps would be something like O(n!) I think anyways. I'm not sure what is possible since the OP has not rigorously defined the operations we are allowed to use.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Can you think of an example that foils the algorithm?

Comment: @Zong Zheing Li My algorithm would do the following to `4 1 2 3 5`: 4 is out of place and should be 5, swap 4 and 5. `5 1 2 3 4.` 1 is out of place and should be 4, swap 1 and 4. `5 4 2 3 1`. 2 is out of place and should be 3, swap 2 and 3. `5 4 3 2 1`. Three swaps, same number of swaps you got.

Comment: @Patashu, so how to manipultae that in my algo...though i have updated..is it correct

Comment: Ok, I've developed a better understanding for this method. No matter what you are always a step closer to the result with each swap, and there are no instances where such a swap would introduce additional necessary swaps. Therefore, I approve.

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar Your algorithm is not correct unless you use something like my algorithm, that permits non-adjacent swaps.

Comment: I am trying with but lost..can u help

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar I outline the steps in my answer. What part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're asking why you're getting 4 steps, and not how to calculate the passes, the correct way to do this is to simply step through your code. In your case the code is simple enough to step through on a piece of paper, in the debugger, or with added debug statements.

```
Original: 3, 4, 2, 5, 1

Pass: 1: 4, 3, 5, 2, 1
Pass: 2: 4, 5, 3, 2, 1
Pass: 3: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
Pass: 4: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Basically what you see is that each iteration you sort one number into the correct position. At the end of pass one 2 is in the correct position. Then 3, 4, 5.

Ah! But this is only 3 passes you say. But you're actually incrementing `passes` regardless of `flag`, which shows you that you actually did one extra step where the array is sorted (in reverse order) but you didn't know this so you had to go through and double check (this was pass 4).

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance, you do not need to start checking the array from the beginning.
Better than the last equal element.

```
static int MinimumSwaps(int[] arr)
{
    int result = 0;
    int temp;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] - 1 == i)
        {
            //once all sorted then
            if(counter==arr.Length)break;
            counter++;
            continue;
        }
        temp = arr[arr[i]-1];
        arr[arr[i] - 1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
        result++;//swapped
        i = counter ;//needs to start from the last equal element
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I have copied/pasted your code, it fails due to the "Index was outside the bounds of the array"...

Answer (score 0):

At the start:

```
{ 3,4,2,5,1}; // passes = 0
```

Round 1 reuslt:

```
{ 4,3,2,5,1};
{ 4,3,5,2,1}; // passes = 1
```

Round 2 reuslt:

```
{ 4,5,3,2,1}; // passes = 2
```

Round 3 reuslt:

```
{ 5,4,3,2,1}; // passes = 3 and flag is set to true
```

Round 4 reuslt:

```
{ 5,4,3,2,1}; // same result and passes is incremented to be 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You fail to mention that the array is supposed to be sorted in descending order, which is usually not the default expected behavior (at least in "C" / C++). To turn:

```
3, 4, 2, 5, 1
```

into:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

one indeed needs 4 (non-adjacent) swaps. However, to turn it into:

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

only two swaps suffice. The following algorithm finds the number of swaps in `O(m)` of swap operations where `m` is number of swaps, which is always strictly less than the number of items in the array, `n` (alternately the complexity is `O(m + n)` of loop iterations):

```
int n = 5;
size_t P[] = {3, 4, 2, 5, 1};

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++ i)
    -- P[i];
// need zero-based indices (yours are 1-based)

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++ i)
    P[i] = 4 - P[i];
// reverse order?

size_t count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++ i) {
    for(; P[i] != i; ++ count) // could be permuted multiple times
        std::swap(P[P[i]], P[i]); // look where the number at hand should be
}
// count number of permutations
```

This indeed finds two swaps. Note that the permutation is destroyed in the process.
The test case for this algorithm can be found [here](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xpolok00/proj/PermutationSwapCount.zip) (tested with Visual Studio 2008).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your question :)

```
static int MinimumSwaps(int[] arr)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int temp;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (arr[i] - 1 == i)
            {
                //once all sorted then
                if(counter==arr.Length)break;
                counter++;
                continue;
            }
            temp = arr[arr[i]-1];
            arr[arr[i] - 1] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            result++;//swapped
            i = 0;//needs to start from the beginning after every swap
            counter = 0;//clearing the sorted array counter
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I have copied/pasted your code, it fails due to the "Index was outside the bounds of the array"... –